# get the first packet of pcap file

Tags: c++, c, wireshark, pcap, winpcap

I am writing code that scan the packets of pcap file.

I use the command

> pcap_next_ex()

to get the next packet.

is there a way to get the first packet- somewhere in the middle of the code, without close and reopen the pcap file?

Thanks.

Comment: Not unless you save the packet somewhere in memory yourself

Comment: I.e., you've already read the first packet once (your first call to `pcap_next_ex()` after `pcap_open_offline()` will give you the first packet in the file), and you want to seek backwards in the file and read the first packet again?

Comment: yes.. I need to seek from the beginning.. and scan the pcap again from the start.
is there a way to load specific packet? for example only from dest_port? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    long pos = ftell(pcap_file(p));
```

before the first `pcap_next_ex()`, and

```
    fseek(pcap_file(p), pos, SEEK_SET);
```

when you want to get the first packet again.